# JS - Create a callback function that accepts an object returned by the function invoking it

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, callback, lodash

I begin with this dataset:

```
var wide_array = [
  {
    "record": 1,
    "associated_location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity": "student",
    "second_identity": "visitor"
  },
  {
    "record": 2,
    "associated_location": "Sutherland",
    "identity": "student",
    "second_identity": "resident"
  },
  {
    "record": 3,
    "associated_location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity": "visitor",
    "second_identity": "worker"
  },
  {
    "record": 4,
    "associated_location": "Miranda",
    "identity": "resident",
    "second_identity": "worker"
  },
  {
    "record": 5,
    "associated_location": "Miranda",
    "identity": "student",
    "second_identity": ""
  },
  {
    "record": 6,
    "associated_location": "Miranda",
    "identity": "worker",
    "second_identity": "resident"
  },
  {
    "record": 7,
    "associated_location": "Sutherland",
    "identity": "worker",
    "second_identity": "resident"
  }
];
```

I then want to convert it from 'wide' format to 'long', which I can do with the following:

```
function processData(wide_array) {
  const long_array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < wide_array.length; i++) {
    const record = wide_array[i];

    // Add "identity"
    long_array.push({ record: record.record, location: record.associated_location, identity_long: record.identity });

    // Add "second_identity"
    long_array.push({ record: record.record, location: record.associated_location, identity_long: record.second_identity });
  }
  return long_array;
}
```

Which gives me:

```
long_array =    
[
    {"record":1,"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"student"},
    {"record":1,"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"visitor"},
    {"record":2,"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"student"},
    {"record":2,"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"resident"},
    {"record":3,"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"visitor"},
    {"record":3,"location":"Kirrawee","identity_long":"worker"},
    {"record":4,"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"resident"},
    {"record":4,"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"worker"},
    {"record":5,"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"student"},
    {"record":5,"location":"Miranda","identity_long":""},
    {"record":6,"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"worker"},
    {"record":6,"location":"Miranda","identity_long":"resident"},
    {"record":7,"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"worker"},
    {"record":7,"location":"Sutherland","identity_long":"resident"}
];
```

I would like to asynchronously pass the `long_array` object created by `processData` into the following `addItemCounts` function:

```
groupByKeys = ['location', 'identity'];

  function addItemCounts(long_array, groupByKeys) {
  var groups = _.groupBy(long_array, obj => {
    return groupByKeys.map(key => obj[key]).join('-');
  });

  return _.map(groups, g => ({
    ...g[0],
    count: g.length
  }));
}

grouped_and_counted = addItemCounts(long_array, groupByKeys);
```

Which returns:

```
grouped_and_counted = [
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "student",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "visitor",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "location": "Kirrawee",
    "identity_long": "worker",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "student",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "resident",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "location": "Sutherland",
    "identity_long": "worker",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "resident",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "worker",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "student",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "location": "Miranda",
    "identity_long": "",
    "count": 1
  }
];
```

My question is, how can I rewrite the `processData` function to take `addItemCounts` as a callback, which takes the output returned by `processData` and an array (`groupByKeys`) as arguments?

In a synchronous context, I would achieve what I want like this:

```
// Step one:
intermediary_object = processData(input);

// Step two:
output_object = addItemCounts(intermediary_object, ['location', 'identity']);
```

However that wont work asynchronously, so I need to rewrite `processData` to take `addItemCounts` as a callback function to execute asynchronously.

Asynchronously, what I want to do looks more like the following pseudocode:

```
processData(wide_array, function(long_array, /* returned by processData */
                                 groupByKeys)) /* ... etc */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite `processData` to accept the function `addItemCounts` as it's second parameter like this:

```
processData(wide_array, addItemsCounts);
```

After that call `addItemsCounts(long_array, groupByKeys)` from the body after you form the `long_array`.

`groupByKey` can also be made a parameter of `processData` if you have it created from a different context.

**Final code**

```
groupByKeys = ['location', 'identity_long'];

function addItemCounts(long_array, groupByKeys) {
    var groups = _.groupBy(long_array, obj => {
        return groupByKeys.map(key => obj[key]).join('-');
    });
    
    return _.map(groups, g => ({
        ...g[0],
        count: g.length
    }));
}
function processData(wide_array, addItemsCounts, groupByKeys) {
    const long_array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < wide_array.length; i++) {
        const record = wide_array[i];
    
        // Add "identity"
        long_array.push({ record: record.record, location: record.associated_location, identity_long: record.identity });
    
        // Add "second_identity"
        long_array.push({ record: record.record, location: record.associated_location, identity_long: record.second_identity });
    }
    return addItemsCounts(long_array, groupByKeys);
}
```

This is how most functions accepting a callback parameter work.

Edit: Added [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xozj59uw/)

Comment: Thanks, can you demonstrate this working? Then I can select yours as the official answer. Right now I tried your solution and got no output using `output = processData(wide_array, addItemCounts, groupByKeys); console.log(output);`

Comment: Edit: I did get output but it was wrong - try it out and see. The return object is wrong.

Comment: I can see that the output is what is expected [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xozj59uw/).

I think it was a problem with the groupByKey using `identity` instead of `identity_long`.